# Android widget config with homescreen visible

Tags: android, widget

I am making an app which has a widget, which has a black background. The alpha of the black background can be changed in a widget config screen from transparent to fully opaque black. 
My question is about the config activity. Id like to show the widget in the middle of the screen, with its area transparent, so the home screen behind it is visible, so the user can pick which alpha suits it the most. Kind of like the music player Shuttle has it. How can it be done? Can I somehow take a screenshot of the background without all the icons, or do I somehow get a reference to the home screen background?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay Ive got it, what you need to do is use this in the config theme

```
<style name="MyWidgetConfigTheme" parent="@style/AppTheme">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowShowWallpaper">true</item>
</style>
```